# Echo and set command used to work. Now they dont in the same device. How can I fix it? batch

Tags: batch-file

It used to work but now it doesn't.
Code:
`set message="HelloWorld" echo %message%`
Output:
`ECHO is off`

Comment: This is not a minimal example of your problem. because the code as it would work

Answer (score 0):

It used to work, until you put your code into parenthesis.

```
@echo off
set message="HelloWorld"
echo %message%
```

Output:

> "HelloWorld"

```
@echo off
(
set message="HelloWorld"
echo %message%
)
```

Output:

> Echo is OFF